# Android MediaRecorder IllegalStateException. start()/stop() called in invalid state

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I am building an app in which I need to record camera without previewing while a video is displayed.

I am using the deprecated class `android.hardware.camera` because it would suit my needs. I have been having issues with the MediaRecorder class.

I set all of myMediaRecorder needed parameters as you can see in the code below:

```
if (myMediaRecorder == null) {
    myMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
}
try {
    if (myCamera == null) {
        myCamera = Camera.open(Integer.parseInt(getFrontFacingCameraId()));
    }
    myCamera.unlock();
    myMediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);
    //myCamera.lock();
    myMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    myMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);       
    myMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(myVideoView.getWidth(),myVideoView.getHeight());             
    myMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);                 myMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);                    myMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
    myMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(new FileOutputStream(outputFile.getAbsolutePath()).getFD());
    myMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    myMediaRecorder.prepare();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I then add Listeners to handle triggers related to my playing video and recorded content as you can see here.

```
playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    myVideoView.requestFocus();
                    myVideoView.start();
                    myMediaRecorder.start();
                    playButton.setText("isRecording");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                myMediaRecorder.stop();
                myMediaRecorder.release();
                myMediaRecorder=null;
                myCamera.release();
                myCamera=null;
                playButton.setText("stopped Recording");
            }
        });
```

I am targeting SDK Version 25 with minSdkVersion set to 23. I have those following permission explicitly declared both in my manifest and by coding:

> Camera, Record Audio, Write & Read External Storage.

Plus those in my manifest :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />
```

My main problem here is that I cannot access to MediaRecorder current state, which leads me to illegal states when calling both start and stop methods.

You can read my stacktrace here:

```
E/ExtendedMediaRecorder: start called in an invalid state: 2 mIsPaused = 0
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.reacteam.reactoplayer.PlayerActivity$1.onClick(PlayerActivity.java:125)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5205)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21164)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:167)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5514)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (3, 0)
E/ExtendedMediaRecorder: stop called in an invalid state: 2
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.reacteam.reactoplayer, PID: 19210
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException
                      at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
                      at com.reacteam.reactoplayer.PlayerActivity$2.onCompletion(PlayerActivity.java:135)
                      at android.widget.VideoView$3.onCompletion(VideoView.java:483)
                      at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2821)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:167)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5514)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I have tried a lot of differents architecture for my MediaRecorder declaration, hopelessly.

I may have missed something crucial but my main disapointment is not being able to access MediaRecord in this kind of way

```
if (myMediaRecord.getState() == "PREPARED") {
    myMediaRecord.start();
}
```

Note here that I add my listeners just after my prepare() statement.

My question is, did I do anything wrong? Am I forced to use Camera2 Api which I find complicated for few advantages? Is there a way to record camera input without MediaRecorder Api?

Comment: Have You implemented runtime permission request?

Comment: try to setVideoEncoder call after setOutputFormat() and before prepare().

Comment: Yes, I have implemented runtime permission request, that's what i meant by "I have those following permission explicitly declared both in my manifest and by coding"

I also call setOutputFormat before setVideoEncoder and prepare.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow MediaRecord document offcial. Your code maybe is not follow the instruction. The order of functions call must be right.

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(_path);
```